# Greasmonkey persistent Iframe or overlay across many pages within a single website

Tags: javascript, include, cross-domain, greasemonkey, frame

I have a script for Greasemonkey and I have managed to add a element to a page that's sort of easy but I would like to add a persistent frame so that each time I move between pages on the website like /page1.php /page2.php etc the frame wont be refreshed.

Has anyone got a suggestion for a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you could rebuild/refresh the frame, but storing the content using cookies, indexedDB or localStorage.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage